# if a person is no longer needed, can I say that he/she is no longer "necessary"?

Tags: word-choice

Basically, I am asking whether it is grammatically correct to describe a person as "necessary" or unnecessary.

I'd appreciate it if anyone can help me with that.

Comment: It is grammatical. Whether it is polite depends on context.

Comment: Not enough context.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of a workforce, when an employer no longer needs an employee's services they would denote that they are no longer required rather than saying that someone is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context.

For example, people are necessary to build a human pyramid.

However, in most other contexts it's usually what the person provides that's necessary or unnecessary.

For example, your presence is unnecessary as we already have enough volunteers.

I would stick with saying someone's presence, time, help, input, contribution etc is necessary or unnecessary, rather than just saying it about a person. It's more specific, grammatically correct, and polite.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more natural to say that the thing the person is offering is not needed or necessary rather than the person himself.

Examples:

Your help is not necessary anymore.

Your input is not necessary . We've already made up our minds.

Mr.. Smith's assistance is no longer necessary.

Comment: "Your position is no longer necessary."